# Directx 11 full screen

Tags: c++, directx, directx11

I build simple directx 11 application in c++ that draw square to screen.

Also check in the end of the program when I close the last peace of directx the number of free reference.

This work great in normal window but in full screen the reference count return 1.
I did some checks and I realised that if I destroy the window before I am closing the swap chain it works even in full screen.

My question is how can I close the swap chain with reference count of 0 without destroying the window before.

Comment: Make sure you've detached and destroyed any render target views of the swap chain's back buffer.

Comment: I wrote in my question that if I not in full screen it work perfect.That is why I think that I realese everything.

Comment: I did some more test and I realized that even if I start my aplication in full screen but move to normal screen(using alt+enter) it closed perfect.